# Error 0x80070570: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

Tags: windows, files

The problem is:
When I edit a file on ubuntu 16.04 LTS, it gets corrupted on windows!
What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You might already have NTFS issues on your Windows partition, that now only come to light because you access the NTFS drive using LInux.  Try booting in Windows, open a command prompt and type `CHKDSK /F C:` (assuming the disk you access is C:).  If the drive is locked, you need to reboot to actually have CHKDSK execute during bootup.  Alternatively, under Linux do `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1`, where `/dev/sda1` is your NTFS disk.  Make sure it is unmounted.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Windows solved my problem automatically :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, formatting the drive could be the best option for you to fix “the file or directory is corrupted and unreadable” error. Here’s how you can format a hard disk:
•   Find the affected hard disk partition and right-click on it
•   Choose the format option on a drop-down menu
•   Then, choose the file system and click on the Quick Format option.
•   Click on the ‘Start’ option to begin the formatting process.

Answer (score 0):

Do `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1`, where `/dev/sda1` is your NTFS disk. Make sure it is unmounted.